PubSub Subscription comes back empty
I'm trying to test if my publish is working, so I am using this subscriber. The publish prints a message id and if I use gcloud cli, I can confirm it's working. However when I try to do it programmatically, it doesn't seem to be working.
It prints "Listening for messages on projects..." But "Iiii..." or "dataaaaa..." print statements don't seem to be getting hit. Not sure what's going on, how do I confirm if the receiver is working or not?
public static Subscriber subscribeAsync() {
    ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName =
            ProjectSubscriptionName.of(PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID, PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION_ID);

    // Instantiate an asynchronous message receiver.
    MessageReceiver receiver =
            (PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) -> {
                // Handle incoming message, then ack the received message.
                System.out.println("Iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii: " + message.getMessageId());
                System.out.println("Dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa: " + message.getData().toStringUtf8());
                consumer.ack();
            };

    Subscriber subscriber = null;
    Optional<CredentialsProvider> credentialsProviderOptional = getCredentialFromProvider();
    if(!credentialsProviderOptional.isPresent()) {
        return null;
    }

    subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver)
   //                .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProviderOptional.get())
            .build();
    // Start the subscriber.
    subscriber.addListener(new ApiService.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void failed(ApiService.State from, Throwable failure) {
            System.err.println(failure);
        }
    }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
    subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
    System.out.printf("Listening for messages on %s:\n", subscriptionName);

    return subscriber;
}

